# How can a turtle tell if a turtle has already stamped where it is standing?

Tags: netlogo

What is the test for a turtle seeing a stamp underneath it? So something like

```
if pcolor = red[...]
```

only for a stamped colour?

Answer (score 1):

[This is not possible](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#drawing)- a stamp is placed on the drawing layer, which is inaccessible to the turtles- it is solely for visualization. For tracking turtle movement / visits / etc it's likely best to record those values in the patches, especially because a turtle is not really 'where' its shape is in that it is solely accessing / writing values at its xy center.